# Is there a way in VSCode to automatically switch Python interpreter depending on the directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using a monorepo with multiple packages in separate directories. Poetry is in charge of package management including creating the virtual environment.

I wish VS Code would use the right Python interpreter for each package individually. Is that possible? My workaround is to open a separate window with the directory containing a package, so all of its files would use the right interpreter.

Comment: use Multi Root Workspace, now you have a `.vscode/settings.json` for each folder and that can contain a separate Python Interpreter path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### You can open multiple folders in vscode and select the interpreter for each folder individually.

1. Select `Add Folder to Workspace` in the menu. As a simple example I have added three folders

   [image]

   [image]
2. Then click on the python interpreter version in the lower right corner (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter`)

   [image]
3. Choose a folder, here I choose `folder1`

   [image]
4. Now select interpreter for `folder1` folder

   [image]

The same operation continues to select interpreters for `folder2` and `folder3`.

Of course this is just the basics, you can also create virtual environments for each folder and then choose the interpreter for the virtual environment for each folder.

For example, I created a virtual environment `.venv2` under the **folder2**, the same step 2 and 3, and then I selected the interpreter under the virtual environment `.venv2`.

[image]

There is also a way to specify the default interpreter path in the **settings.json**, but after setting it also requires step 2 and 3 and then select it in the selection panel.

[image]

When you modify the folder settings, the **.vscode** folder and the **settings.json** file will be automatically generated under the folder. The contents of the **settings.json** file are the settings you just modified

[image]

*And this step is reversible. You can manually create the **.vscode** folder and add the **settings.json** file in it. And enter the corresponding settings in the **settings.json** file.*

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering about the tests. The tests seem to run outside of the chosen environments... Maybe I'll create a separate issue for that

Comment: Thanks @JialeDu but adding the folders in this manner means that vscode no longer picks up the root of the folder which contains .gitignore and git itself - any suggestions?