Vscode is throwing up an error when i try to import numpy even though its installed in my environment, how do i fix this
I'm trying to write some code and vscode is crying about me importing numpy or any package for that matter. Specifically the error message was "Import "numpy" could not be resolved  Pylance  reportMissingImports"text then i checked which packages are installed on the environment (~/anaconda3/bin/python) through
pip list 

and it lists numpy (this was all done on VScode zsh cmd line).
It could be the fact I'm trying to run my code in a jupyter notebook inside vscode but I've followed the instructions laid out here and I can run normal python commands fine just nothing with importing packages. under the same environment i can run it all fine in a .py file, though i get the same error if i change to the recommended environment (/usr/bin/python3) and i just can't understand what is actually going on, as ive tried installing numpy and it just says its already there, which i agree with.
I'm using a mac please let me know if ive missed any details im kind of new to all this nitty gritty stuff.

You've mentioned Jupyter, Anaconda, and VSCode here.  What are you actually using?  You need to be aware that EACH of those environments can have its own installation of Python, separate from all the rest.  You can tell VSCode which installation to use, and that's likely the solution to your problem.

so im using a conda environment on a jupyter notebook inside vscode. i dont know how to tell them what im using. ive seen PATH dotted around but where do i access this or tell where everything is actually installed on my machine

The VSCode version of Python is shown in the status bar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240838/how-to-tell-vs-code-to-use-the-correct-python   Did you do a "conda install numpy"?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You may need to check which python you are working on for your projects and packages installed.use which python to print current working interpreter.

How about just "don't change to the recommended environment"?
Also please include a picture so we know what's the situation. like this:

You can also use "python3 -m venv venv" or use other tools like "uv" to create virtual environments. Then VSCode will recommend them first.
